# Python fbs on alpine linux - missing PyQt packages

Tags: python, pyqt5, alpine-linux

I want to compile my project on a CI-runner with Alpine Linux.
The project is made in Python with the fbs module.
It can be started with `fbs run`, frozen with `fbs freeze` and it's possible to make an installer with `fbs installer`.

However, if I try to compile it using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - alias pip="pip3"
  - apk add --update --no-cache python3 python3-dev
  - python3 -m ensurepip
  - rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip
  - pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools
  - ls
  - cd code/
  - apk add py3-qt5
  - pip3 install wheel
  - pip3 install -r production.txt

test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  script:
  - pytest

production:
  type: deploy
  tags:
    - docker-in-docker
  script:
  - ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 ldd
  - ln -s /lib /lib64 
  - fbs freeze
  - fbs installer
```

All comands work except `fbs freeze` and `fbs installer`.
When `fbs freeze` is executed the following error is thrown:

```
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so: PyTuple_SetItem: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so: PyLong_AsLong: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so: PyDict_GetItemString: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so: PyObject_GetAttrString: symbol not found
...
Error relocating /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtNetwork.so: PyExc_TypeError: symbol not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 433, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 587, in assemble
    self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/compat.py", line 509, in exec_command_all
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'objcopy': 'objcopy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fbs", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbs/__main__.py", line 17, in _main
    fbs.cmdline.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbs/cmdline.py", line 30, in main
    fn(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbs/builtin_commands/__init__.py", line 118, in freeze
    freeze_linux(debug=debug)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbs/freeze/linux.py", line 8, in freeze_linux
    run_pyinstaller(debug=debug)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fbs/freeze/__init__.py", line 36, in run_pyinstaller
    run(args, check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?